# Curl Multi Threading

Tags: php, mysql

i am finding a Curl function which can open particular no. of webpage open at a time also there will no output or returndata false will more good . I need to access 5-10 url at a same time .. I heard abt Curl Multi Threading but dont have proper function or class to use it ..

i find some by searching but most of them seems to be loop mean it i not using continuous connection just one after one ! I want something which can connect multiple connection at a time not one by one !

I made one :

```
function mutload($url){
if(!is_array($url)){
exit;
}

for($i=0;$i<count($url);$i++){
// create both cURL resources
$ch[] = curl_init();
$ch[] = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_URL, $url[$i]);
curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);

}
//create the multiple cURL handle
$mh = curl_multi_init();

for($i=0;$i<count($url);$i++){
//add the two handles
curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch[$i]);
}
$active = null;
//execute the handles
do {
$mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
    do {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
    } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
 }
}

//close the handles
for($i=0;$i<count($url);$i++){
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch[$i]);
}
curl_multi_close($mh);
}
```

ok ! but i m confused that will it connect all the urls at a time or one by one ! mre over i am geeting the content also i only want to connect or request to the site do not need ay content from there i used RETURNTRASFER,false but didnt work .. please hlep me thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [`curl_multi_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) family of functions. Have a look at [`curl_multi_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php).

Set `CURLOPT_NOBODY` to prevent curl from downloading any cotent.

Comment: as u told i made one script please have a look !

Comment: @SoumoGorai Updated the answer with `CURLOPT_NOBODY`. The `multi_` functions will send requests in parallel. Could you clarify a little bit what your remaining question is? I'm having trouble reading your question, probably because English is not my first language and you seem to have a very creative orthography. Am I right in assuming `mre over` stands for moreover and `abt` for about?

Comment: your English is very good ! i dont have prob to read it well that are some common words these days to used anyways ! can you tell me can my script send requests parallel or one by one ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test your code but curl_multi adds items to a queue from a loop and process them in parallel. Sometimes there can be issues if you are trying to load 100s of URLs, but it should be fine for a few URLs. If you have long DNS lookups or slow servers, all your results will have to wait for the slowest request.

This code is tested and should work, it is somewhat similar to yours:

http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/01/26/how-to-use-curl_multi-without-blocking/

Comment: i have used this script which u told "Rolling Curl" . but i dont have to download like 1000 or more than that mostly 20-30 or rarely 50 . also Rolling Curl taking much time it taking 468 for 3 Jobs and my function takin 140 for 3 Jobs ! anywyas can you tell me thaat can my function run parallel connection or not ? thanks

Comment: curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0); This must be true to return anything